# For how many residues $x\pmod{p}$ is $x^{-1} \in [1,(p-1)/2]$?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

> Given a prime $p$, let $N_p$ denote the number of  $x \in [1, (p-1)/2]$
>   such that $$x^{-1} \pmod{p} \in [1, (p-1)/2]$$  What is the limiting distribution of
>   $$S_n := \left \{\frac{N_p}{(p-1)/2}\, : \, 1\le \text{prime} \, p \le n \right\}$$ as $n\to\infty$?

Numerical evidence suggests this quantity is distributed like a normal random variable with mean $1/2$ and standard deviation given by $f(n)$, where the graph of $f$ on $3\le n \le 300$ looks like the below data, which suggests something like $(n\log(n))^{-1}$:

[image]

Comment: It looks like your plot allows $p$ which are not prime, despite your formulation of the problem.  Note that only in the title do you mention working *mod* $p$.

Comment: My mistake, fixed the problem statement. Note that the plot is $n$ against the st.dev of $S_n$.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused - $x \mapsto x^{-1}\pmod p$ is surely a 1:1 mapping from $[1..p-1]$ to itself so the number should always be $\frac{p-1}2$, ne?

Comment: You're right, I've misrecorded my question. Fixed again.

Comment: @SameerKailasa: To obtain a guess for the decay of the standard deviation from the data, I recommend looking at a log-log plot, and best fitting a line (I suspect it the log-log plot will be linear). Say the slope of the line in the log-log plot is $\alpha<0$. Then we expect the standard deviation to look like $n^\alpha$ (rather than $(n\log n)^{-1}$.)

Comment: If you don't get an answer, or a reference or link to one fairly soon, I suggest cross-posting to MathOverload for this Q.